# jQuery delay/pause an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to scroll a table's scrollbar

```
$('.myTable').animate({
    scrollTop: myPositon
}, 45000, function() {

});
```

Now I have the following event listening for the scroll bar position

```
$('.myTable').bind('scroll', function() {
   //if the scroll bar reaches certain position
   //pause the scrolling for 5 seconds

 });
```

I have the code to check if the scroll bar reaches certain position, the questions is how to pause the scrolling/or animation for 5 second within the bind function and afterwards automatically resume the animation?

I know there's delay and clearQueue. but calling:

`$('.myTable').delay(5000) or $('.myTable').clearQueue` does seem to have any effect

Comment: You want to make the table un-scrollable? Just remove the scrollbars with overflow:hidden

Comment: could you provide a test-case in jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Instead of pausing and resuming an animation, what about just animating the first step, pause 5 seconds, then do a new animation for the next step? There is also a `step` option you can specify for animate to make a callback during animation

Comment: Thanks MrOBrian. That's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You need to use setInterval and clearInterval methods.

Answer (score 0):

May be below html solve your problem

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #abc;
                left: 0px;
                top:30px;
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="go">Go</button>
        <button id="stop">STOP!</button>
        <button id="back">Back</button>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <script>
            /* Start animation */
            $("#go").click(function () {
                $(".block").animate({
                    left: '+=100px'
                }, 2000);
            });

            /* Stop animation when button is clicked */
            $("#stop").click(function () {
                $(".block").stop();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".block").animate({
                        left: '+=100px'
                    }, 2000)
                }, 1000);
            });

            /* Start animation in the opposite direction */
            $("#back").click(function () {
                $(".block").animate({
                    left: '-=100px'
                }, 2000);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```